# Get attribute of a xml by comparing two xml data

Tags: javascript

I`m trying to get the attribute value of a xml by comparing it to **another xml**,as follows:

**xmlData1** variable has xml like--->

```
<Root>
  <RNA A="100" x="table1" y="car11"/>
  <RNA A="101" x="table2" y="car12"/>
  <RNA A="102" x="table3" y="car13"/>
  <RNA A="103" x="table4" y="car14"/>
  <RNA A="104" x="table5" y="car15"/>
  <RNA A="105" x="table6" y="car16"/>
  <RNA A="106" x="table7" y="car17"/>
  <RNA A="107" x="table8" y="car18"/>
  <RNA A="108" x="table9" y="car19"/>
</Root>
```

**xmlData2** variable has xml like --->

```
<Ina>
  <RNA B="100" x="table1" y="car11"/>
  <RNA B="101" x="table2" y="car12"/>
  <RNA B="102" x="table3" y="car13"/>
</Ina>
```

Here i `ve to compare like

```
if(xmlData1.getAttribute(x)==xmlData2.getAttribute(x) then
//code goes
```

How to achive this???please help

Comment: it's not clear what you actually want to compare

Comment: I`m sorry if I was not clear,I just need to compare 'x' attribute value to one another,if matches then get 'x' attribute value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's reasonable simple. First off, you parse the xml. I've put together a X-browser function that fits your needs rather well, actually. You can [find it here](http://jsfiddle.net/d6cgf/1/)
Uncomment this line:

```
keep.push(parsed);//last element of array is the full DOM
```

Just call it like so:

```
var data1 = parseXML(xml1,'RNA','x');//xml1 is the first xml string
var data2 = parseXML(xml2,'RNA','x');//xml2 === second xml string
var xml1Parsed = data1.splice(-1);//assign document to variable
var xml2Parsed = data2.splice(-1);
//get the nodes of intrest
var RNA1 = xml1Parsed.getElementsByTagName('RNA');
var RNA2 = xml2Parsed.getElementsByTagName('RNA');
```

both `data1` and `data2` are now arrays, just iterate over them:

```
for (var i=0;i<data1.length;i++)
{
    if (data1[i] === data2[i])//attribute x is the same
    {//check whatever you need
        if (RNA1[i].getAttribute('y') === RNA2[i].getAttribute('y'))
        {
            console.log('node ' + i + ' is alike');//do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

---

Just for completeness and clarity, this is the function as used in this example:

```
var parseXML = (function(w,undefined)
{
    'use strict';
    var parser,i,ie,parsed;
    ie = false;
    switch (true)
    {
        case w.DOMParser !== undefined:
            parser = new w.DOMParser();
        break;
        case new w.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") !== undefined:
            parser = new w.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            parser.async = false;
            ie = true;
        break;
        default :
            throw new Error('No parser found');
    }
    return function(xmlString,getTags,getAttr)
    {
        var tags,keep = [];
        if (ie === true)
        {
            parser.loadXML(xmlString);
            parsed = parser;
        }
        else
        {
            parsed = parser.parseFromString(xmlString,'text/xml');
        }
        tags = parsed.getElementsByTagName(getTags);
        for(i=0;i<tags.length;i++)
        {
            if (!getAttr || getAttr === 'textContent')
            {
                keep.push(tags[i].textContent);
                continue;
            }
            if (getAttr && tags[i].getAttribute(getAttr))
            {
                keep.push(tags[i].getAttribute(getAttr));
            }
        }
        keep.push(parsed);//last element of array is the full DOM
        return keep;
    }
})(this);//assuming global declaration, if not: replace with window
```

Comment: Why are you assuming the OP wants to use DOM functions? He did not say he's working in a browser environment. Just kidding :)

Comment: @Ootegem: Thanks for the reply and answer.I feel terrible to understand the code.Is there a way better than this and simple??

Comment: @user1495475 yes, use jQuery :)

Comment: @wroniasty: No I can`t use jQuery,i got to use javascript for this.

Comment: @wroniasty the "jQuery IS javascript" is a tired and worthless argument.  If you really don't have anything better to offer then please don't recommend garbage.  For many jQuery developers "jQuery is JavaScript" is an allusion to "JavaScript is jQuery" so as to suggest an inability to imagine operating outside jQuery for even the most simple of tasks.  Furthermore, jQuery is not native JavaScript as it is a bulky inefficient framework that is not always available in the real world.

Comment: @austincheney just for your information, the `DOMParser` you used in your answer is also a part of an extremely bulky framework.

Comment: @austincheney I did not mean to say that jQuery and Javascript are one thing - just that jQuery is written in pure javascript, and using it in no way differs from the `DOM` supplied by browsers.

Comment: @wroniasty: on the DOM functions: you needn't be in a browser to parse markup, and apply DOM functions to a _parsed string_ :). @user1495475: This is fairly simple code (except for the `parseXML` function) but that function is X-browser (even IE6, I believe), and needn't be changed. Just lookup the various methods on MDN to find out what everything does. I must admit, I tend to use closures a lot, google how they work and you'll get it soon enough. And, no, sorry, but this is (IMHO) the best X-browser way to do this. It's stable, quite safe and doesn't depend on a bulky framwork like jQ

Comment: incedently: why the down-vote? I don't mind DV's but at least have the decency to tell me what's wrong with my code. I use this all the time, but I'm open to suggestions, if my code can be improved, let me know

Comment: @wroniasty: what makes you say the `DOMParser` object is part of a bulky framework? all major browsers (except for IE) support it natively, and [on the MDN pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser) there's an extension for browsers that aren't shipped with it, that's only 40 lines of code long! in what way is that bulky?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem isn't any browser a rather bulky framework? You say 'pure javascript' and then you use the `DOM` provided by a heavy, memory hungry piece of software, and at the same time you discredit a 20kB library built on top of that software - that just doesn't sit right with me.

Comment: @wroniasty: Well, if you're already burdened with such a bulky, memory hungry piece of software, why add an extra framwork _that uses that same bulky, memory hungry software, too_? It's not only size (in bytes) that matter: jQuery is and will always be slower, like any framework or tool-kit. jQuery isn't modular enough IMO, that's why I call it bulky

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16830/discussion-between-wroniasty-and-elias-van-ootegem)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to parse XML:

```
var result1 = $(xmlData1)
var result2 = $(xmlData2)
```

Then you can use jQuery to search/compare within your XML:

```
if (result1.find('RNA[A=100]').attr ('x') == result2.find('RNA[B=100]').attr('x'))
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Please, don't assume jQuery: OP didn't use jQuery in his snippets, and didn't include jQ tag.

Comment: It's a library that accomplishes what he wanted. He did not ask how to implement an XML parser, just how to compare two XML elements.

Comment: @wroniasty:No actually Elias is right here,but the code is complicate to understand for me.I just needed a small function for that.

Comment: FYI, the `$` function call that comes from jQuery does almost exactly what Elias posted

Answer (score 0):

To find differences in XML try using [Pretty Diff](http://prettydiff.com/).  It does all this for you even if the attributes are different orders and the white space is completely inconsistent.

Here is how you can do this without a fancy tool.

```
var comparexml = function (x, y) {
        var a = (typeof DOMParser === "function") ? true : false,
            b = [],
            c = [],
            d = 0,
            e = 0,
            f = 0,
            g = function () {},
            h = {},
            i = {};
        if (a) {
            g = new DOMParser();
            b = g.parseFromString(x, "application/xml").getElementsByTagName("RNA");
            c = g.parseFromString(y, "application/xml").getElementsByTagName("RNA");
        } else {
            g = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            g.async = false;
            h = g.loadXML(x);
            i = g.loadXML(y);
            b = h.getElementsByTagName("RNA");
            c = i.getElementsByTagName("RNA");
        }
        d = Math.min(b.length, c.length);
        for (e = 0; e < d; e += 1) {
            for (f = 0; f < d; f += 1) {
                if (b[e].getAttribute("a") === c[f].getAttribute("b")) {
                    if (b[e].getAttribute("x") === c[f].getAttribute("x")) {
                        //your special logic goes in here
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

That code example may not work cross browser, so again I recommend a fancy tool like Pretty Diff.

Comment: I have no idea if this will work correctly in IE8, but I modified the code to support DOM parsing from an activeX control.  Try it now.

Comment: It successfully parsed but threw error at line "g.loadXML(x).getElementsByTagName("RNA")" like "Object doesn`t support this property or method"

Comment: It seems to have a problem with chaining.  I broke those into two different lines.  It should work now.

Comment: :Thanks for the code sir.It works.Actually the previous code also works.I had made a mistake.Sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: :Thanks for the code sir.It works.Actually the previous code also works.I had made a mistake.Sorry for the inconvinience.I got a doubt here why are we considering "d = Math.min(b.length, c.length);".why min here??

Comment: The variable `d` is used to tell the for loops when to stop.  Variable `d` is assigned to the shortest length of the two different node lists, because there is nothing else to compare.  If you want to run operations against the extra nodes from the longer list then simply subtract the length of the longer list to the shorter list and run a for loop for that duration after the other for loops complete.